# How to simulate MVC routing in WebForm ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes

You all have seen how MVC minifies URL by default in form of url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}". It's done in RouteConfig.cs.

I'm looking for a way so that a webform URL like `mywebsite.com/Page/Default.aspx?id=100&Browser=ff` changes to `mywebsite.com/Page/Default/100?Browser=ff`, It should be done in Globa.ascx.

There are some posts in StackOverFlow website which instructs how to redirect a reserved URL to a certain page, it's obvious that my question is something else, I'm looking for a way to offer a pattern in Global.ascx.

Answer (score 1):

At the solution explorer, under your project, add a new ASP.NET item "Global.asax"

Add the using statement:

```
using System.Web.Routing;
```

At the Application_Start event, type in your routing URL, for example:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("default1", "Page/Default", "~/Page/Default.aspx");
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("default2", "Page/Default/{controller}/{action}/{id}", "~/Page/Default.aspx");
    }
```

Then, at the page load event:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string controller = RouteData.Values["controller"] + "";
        string action = RouteData.Values["action"] + "";
        string id = RouteData.Values["id"] + "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro, I tried your solution, it works when I type the URL entirly, I faced error 404 when I didn't prepare `control`, `action` and `id` so `mywebsite.com/Page/Default` as URL doesn't work. Do I need `*` in routeUrl `{*control}` ?. Afterall it seems there is no way to simulate MVC routing exactly.

Comment: I have updated my answer above. You need to add another route for pure `mywebsite.com/Page/Default`